# For my android app , How to watch or filter Firebase event for specific user ID and How to get all all users who have triggered a event

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am using Firebase analytics and crashlytics, while there is a way to put userId with event and in the dashboard ( Firebase console ), while i can view events increment or aggregated comparison.

My purpose is to know, when a user or users are not able to complete action.
Suppose there are 3 steps to an action A -> B -> C, I am interested to know if some users don't complete full process, when they quit with other contexts to understand flaws or inefficiencies in our UX.
And If I can check individual user event journey, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The Analytics reports are limited in Firebase. With your use case, you could link your Firebase app to BigQuery. This will allow you to access your raw, unsampled event data along with all of your parameters and user properties and perform your custom analysis there. you can find BigQuery's export schema in this [article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7029846).

To [link](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765) your Firebase project to BigQuery:

1. On the Settings icon, click Project Settings.
2. On the Project Settings page, click the Integrations tab.
3. On the BigQuery card, click Link.

You could also use [Data Studio](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7259176?hl=en). This will help you to make informative reports that you could use in your app.